# Using multer with an express server my file is not uploading to the server

Tags: reactjs, express, multer

This is my first question on stack overflow ever, I have been programming for 3 years. Thanks for the help!

- My code compiles and I can send the post to the correct place and the request looks correct
- I get a 200 return with the info that it worked
- No file is to be seen anywhere, I tried changing directories and it didnt work
- cors is not throwing any errors

Html (jsx) form

```
<Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop}>
              {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                <div className=" space-under">
                  <div {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone" })}>
                    <input {...getInputProps()} />
                    <div className="dropZoneContainer">
                      <div className="dropZoneOverlay">
                        <div>{filesAdded}</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <button
                    className="button"
                    disabled={!filesAdded}
                    onClick={this.handleSubmission}
                  >
                    Submit file
                  </button>
                </div>
              )}
            </Dropzone>
```

File getting sent

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("hash", hash);
formData.append("myfile", files);

fetch("http://localhost:3030/addFile", {
      method: "post",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        this.fileUploadedSuccessfully();
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
};
```

Express Route

```
app.post("/addFile", (req, res) => {
  addFile.handleAddFile(req, res, db);
});
```

Multer part

```
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "/public/uploads/");
  },

  // By default, multer removes file extensions so let's add them back
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

const handleAddFile = (req, res) => {
  let upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("myfile");

  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (!req.body.myfile) {
      return res.send("Please select a file to upload");
    } else if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return res.send(err);
    } else if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }

    res.send(`You have uploaded this ${req.body.hash}`);
  });
};

module.exports = {
  handleAddFile,
};
```

Comment: So to answer my own question:

Dropzone from react-dropzone can allow adding multiple files at once, when this happens it adds also a single file automatically to an array. If you append this array into new formData, when multer is configured to one file, this will leave req.files/req.file inaccessible. You have to make sure that there is a seperate method from react sending either an array or the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending one file or multiple files? In your `Multer` config, you specified `single("myfile");`. Try to `console.log(req.body)` to check if your server received one file, or an array of files (which can have one item).

Comment: req.body contains an object, within this object there is the hash and the myfile that is being uploaded. As per the multer requirements, the file is also appended last in to the formData